# Asp.NET crystal report NullReferenceException on Load method

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, nullreferenceexception

i've got a code as below that perfectly works on localhost but it gives me `NullReferenceException` on server,

Here's the code

```
 ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
 string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MyReport.rpt");
 report.Load(reportPath);
```

I talked with my hosting company and they said supporting v4.0 Crystal reports runtime and i'm using .NET Framework 4.0 and Crystal reports 13.0.2000.0.

EDIT:

Here's the stacktrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.]
   OrderLone.Admin.Menu2_1a.Bind() +17975
   OrderLone.Admin.Menu2_1a.btnCustomDateReport_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +161
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +170
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3803
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide full exception stack trace.

Comment: By the code and exception you provided, it has to do with this line `string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MyReport.rpt");`.  but need the whole NullReferenceException to make an exact determination of the cause.